# Can't format PC after creating another partition?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

The other day I wanted to start fresh again and format my Windows 7 laptop to factory settings. I have the Recovery Partition built in. All I have to do is restart the computer and hit F11 at the boot-up screen.

I went to delete some space off the C: drive to create a backup partition. (Successful) I did this on Windows Vista before and the whole process went well. After creating the partition the colorful bars that is on top of the partitions turned into a different color.

[image]

When I restarted I had an error, something like this:

```
Error 0x000225 Could not start up windows
```

That is when I hit F11 to the recovery Screen. It starts up fine besides that. How can I fix this?

**Laptop Specs:**

[image]

Comment: **Partition Info:**
http://i.imgur.com/Jka6q.png

Comment: Please post your Make and Model of PC for more specific help on this issue, you broke the proprietary MBR when you modified the partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) off of a LiveCD or USB to format the drive or the non-recovery partition and then install Windows in the empty space.